# Three.js - render.shadowmap.enabled = true reduces the maximum distance reached by pointLight

Tags: three.js

I'm working on a solar system simulator using three.js, and I want to implement shadows to simulate moons blocking sunlight from reaching their planets and vice versa. I've done a lot of searching on how to implement shadows properly, and I eventually made the eclipses work. This is the code I used on my light source to make it cast shadows:

```
sunlight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xFDB813, 2, 0, 2); 
sunlight.position.copy(sun.position);       
sunlight.castShadow = true;
sunlight.shadow.mapSize.set(2048, 2048);
```

However, when I add this line to my code:

```
   renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true
```

the maximum distance reached by my pointlight decreases and no longer reaches the farther planets. I tried playing around with the parameters of the light source, but nothing changes. What's wrong with my code? Why does renderer.shadowMap decrease the maximum reach of my light source?

Here's a link to my simplified project

https://jsfiddle.net/hr8yd348/35/

I apologize if the code is confusing, I trimmed my project down to just two planets, one with a moon and one without a moon that is located far away from the sun. The code that seems to break my light source is at light source is at line 134. If you comment out that line, the object will be visible as the light is able to reach it again.

PS. the Center Earth button will make the camera focus on the planet with the moon, while the Center Mars button will make the camera focus on the far away planet

Also, changing the values at shadow.mapSize.set seems to have an effect on the smoothness of the shadow. Can someone please explain? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The pointlight's shadow will be using what is essentially a camera to render the shadowmap. You could try extending the shadow camera's far plane out to see if that helps.

The larger you set your shadow map size, the smoother it will be because it is essentially a texture. The higher resolution the shadow texture is, the smoother the shadow sampling will be.

Answer (score 0):

This is as good as I could get it with some fiddling...
I disabled the animation to be able to iterate...
I cranked shadowmap size to 4096 sqr. I switched to PCFSoftShadowmap and a blur radius of 1.75..

```
sunlight.shadow.mapSize.set(4096,4096);
sunlight.shadow.radius = 1.75;
```

The main problem is that pointlight shadowmapping is inherently low res, far away from the light source, since its a cube shadowmap so the map is tiled amongst 6 faces.

If you want super crispy shadows, you might have to fake it with a spot light that always aims at the moon, or do some kind of custom shader...

Here is the fiddle: I made the Center Earth button, toggle the pause mode..
https://jsfiddle.net/8egcc8eb/